# [Spring][SpringBoot] All annotation configuration for scheduled tasks

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor

Good morning everybody,
First of all, I have to say that [How to go from XML Spring scheduling configuration to annotation/code configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970650/how-to-go-from-xml-spring-scheduling-configuration-to-annotation-code-configurat) topic could answer my question but I don't know Spring working enough to understand it :
According to https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ tuto, I have main Application class and ScheduledTasks class which contains N methods that have to be launched independently (task1 must run in parallel with task2 but 2 task1 must not run in the same time).

Currently, all methods are executed sequentially and I'm asking how to configure that (), if possible only with annotations, withous xml file ?
- Have I to put Async annotation? If so, where to put @EnableAsync : on the Application class or one the ScheduledTasks class ?
- If I have to create xml file, how to link it with my Java classes and tell to main() to take it into account ?
- How to reference in a xml file, a bean which have been created with annotation ?
- Can't I just add new class with @Configuration to define a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with N size ?
- Can/should I have to put this configuration into Application class because it use @SpringBootApplication which include @Configuration tags ?

Has you can see, Spring and SpringBoot are quite confusing for me because I don't used it a lot for the moment and don't know how to mix annotations and xml files.

Thanks a lot for your attention !

Edit1 : 
According to http://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_threadpooltaskexecutor_spring, I created new Conf without bean creation because my ScheduledTasks class is already "beanify" by using @Component if I understood well. It does not do what I want :
it allow all tasks to execute asynchronously (task1 & task2 and task1 & task1) even if I specify fixedDelay instead of fixedRate (@Async used). In the same mind, even with fixedRate instead of fixedDelay and without @Async, task1 are not run parallely (that's not what I want but it's just to understand)

Edit2 : I rollback my work and do not use AsyncConfigurer because this is not async that I want so I added following code to my Application class (or in a new separate @Configuration class (anywhere in fact)) :

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("poolScheduler");
    scheduler.setPoolSize(2);
    return scheduler;
}
```

and it works !!!!
But I don't understand why, this seems to be magic and I hate this in computer science !!! 
--> how does Spring know that it has to use this new bean specifically for my scheduler ? The bean is just created, not associated to my scheduler, no ?

Comment: `@ImportResource("your.xml.file.here")`. It is configuration so where do you thing `@Enable*` annotations should go, hint (again) it is configuration...