# Universal exception handler for @Scheduled tasks in Spring (Boot) with Java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have lots of scheduled tasks in my Spring Boot (ver 1.4.2) application and would like to catch all exceptions from them using one handler like is possible for normal controllers with [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation. This approach does not work for tasks that are defined with @Scheduled annotation because of threading:

```
@Component
public class UpdateJob {
    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 0 * * *")
    public void runUpdateUsers() {
        userService.updateUsers();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void handle(Exception e) {
       // some more logic here
       logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

 }
```

@ExceptionHandler does not work for @Scheduled method (and it turns out it is not meant to). Instead, Spring Boot uses it's own [LoggingErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE_to_4.2.3.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.2.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/support/TaskUtils.LoggingErrorHandler.html):

```
2016-12-08 15:49:20.016 ERROR 23119 --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
```

Can I somehow replace or supply default exception handler for scheduled tasks? Or would it make sense (and is it possible) to switch to [PropagatingErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE_to_4.2.3.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.2.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/support/TaskUtils.PropagatingErrorHandler.html) which as I understand propagates the error further? Is there any other way to achieve the goal using only Java configuration (no XML)?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031613/exception-handling-for-spring-3-2-scheduled-annotation) as it explicitly asks for **a solution based on Java configuration, not XML** (so it is decent to incorporate into Spring Boot project without any XML configuration).

There are also some answers that demonstrate how to configure TaskScheduler from the scratch. Eg this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27970752/1169324) requires that you also define pool size, max pool size, queue capacity. [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-exception) is a solution which also need very extensive configuration. [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html) shows how to configure other aspects, but not how to specify error handling. But **what is the minimal required effort with Java config** so that I can maximally keep Spring Boot default values (thread pools, executor configurations etc).

Comment: Exception handlers are for Web handler methods.

Comment: Please provide reasoning, is there any reason you cannot use exception handler for any method or class? Term "web handler" is applicable to ASP.net, perhaps it is different there?

Comment: It's part of the webmvc infrastructure. It's meant to be used with `@Controller`. Read the javadoc you linked.

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't configure anything. When configuring your `TaskScheduler` set the `ErrorHandler` on it you want to use.

Comment: @M. Deinum, Could you show example? Is it possible to achieve it together with '@Scheduled' annotation?

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example of setting custom error handler (Spring 2.0.2):

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    ConcurrentTaskScheduler scheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setErrorHandler(throwable -> { /* custom handler */ });
    return scheduler;
}
```

Comment: You can customise Spring Boot's default `TaskScheduler` by implementing `TaskSchedulerCustomizer` in your `@Configuration` and just setting the error handler. That lets you keep Spring Boot's default configuration.

Answer (score 7):

You're on the right track with `PropagatingErrorHandler`, but you slightly misunderstood the purpose. It causes the exception to continue further up the stack, causing the scheduled task to not run in the future. Also, it's private to `TaskUtils`, so you can not access it.

You'll need to implement your own `ErrorHandler`, but you can only have a single handler. At a minimum you'll want to log the exception, because you'll no longer have Spring logging it for you.

Assuming you don't have your own custom `TaskScheduler` bean, to create your own `ErrorHandler` in Spring Boot, implement `org.springframework.boot.task.TaskSchedulerCustomizer` in your @Configuration class.

```
@Override
public void customize(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
    taskScheduler.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
}

private static class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Scheduled task threw an exception: {}", t.getMessage(), t);
    }
}
```

Because `ErrorHandler` is a `@FunctionalInterface` you can do:

```
taskScheduler.setErrorHandler(t -> { /* Handle exception here */});
```

(This is based on Spring Boot 2.1.8)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, `@ExceptionHandler` is for Spring MVC controllers.

In case you want to have exception handling logic for single scheduler, easiest and most maintainable would be to wrap it into try-catch block and handle error there.

If you want to apply same error handler for various schedulers, follow @M. Deinum's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! This specific @ExceptionHandler seems not to be designed for this purpose indeed. I would only like to provide error handler, but not change other executor properties. I understand that there is no way to provide exception handling to scheduled tasks (as a @Bean?) unless I am also willing to manage the scheduler itself?

Comment: Please see the comment on `TaskSchedulerCustomizer` below, seems like a clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think using AOP might solve your problem.

**Steps**

1. Create a class called UpdateJobAOP and annotate with @Component and @Aspect annotation.
2. In UpdateJobAOP class create a method called all() and annotate with @Pointcut("execution(* com.foo.bar.UpdateJob.*(..))")
3. Create another method in UpdateJobAOP class called afterThrowing(Exception ex) or whatever and annotate with @AfterThrowing(pointcut="all()", throwing="ex")
4. Print the stacktrace and check if all the exceptions are caught.

**FYI** :
I have worked on AOP on individual methods and caught its exceptions and logged it but personally I have not come up with the use case you have specified till now. The above solution is just a suggestion.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class UpdateJobAOP {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.foo.bar.UpdateJob.*(..))")
    public void all()  {}

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="all()", throwing="ex")
    public void afterThrowing(Exception ex)  {

        // Do what you want
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have XML configuration, this works:

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="customThreadPoolTaskScheduler"  />
<bean id="customThreadPoolTaskScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="poolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="customScheduledTaskErrorHandler" />
</bean>
<bean id="customScheduledTaskErrorHandler" class="myapp.ScheduledJobErrorHandler"/>
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="customThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
     <task:scheduled method="method1" cron="0 0 7 * * *"/>
     <task:scheduled method="method2" cron="0 0 7 * * *"/>
     etc.
```

Note that this **replaces** any `<task:scheduler>` that you might have. You are now directly defining a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` which allows you to specify an `errorHandler`.

Implement the `myapp.ScheduledJobErrorHandler` class with the required method:

```
public class ScheduledJobErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
         //...
    }
```